# database primary key based on variable number of customer subdivisions

Tags: mysql, sql, grails, database-design, grails-orm

Doing this in Groovy/Grails and GORM with a MySQL DB.

When storing data for our different customers we need to be able to identify their subdivisions.  Some will have 0 levels of subdivisions.  Some, 1, 2, 3, levels etc.  We'd like to allow any number of levels of subdivisions, but could settle for a fixed number, such as 5, 7 or 10.

For instance:

Company ABC has 2 subdivision levels:

Company) ABC (the root level)
Subdivision Level 1) ABC->Div1, ABC->Div2, ABC->Div3
Subdivision Level 2) ABC->Div1->SubDiv1, ABC->Div1->SubDiv2, ABC->Div1->SubDiv3

Company DEF has 1 levels:

Company) DEF (the root level)
Level 1) DEF->Div1, DEF->Div2, DEF->Div3

We need to define both 1 to 1 and 1 to many unique attributes for each level (for example associate an address with ABC->Div1->SubDiv3)

And Company ABC may want us to display a certain image for all instances for Div2 and all of Div2's subdivisions.

The question is, how is it best to create a variable number of division levels for an identifier or primary key to then use as a foreign key on related data?

Have a fixed number of columns (like 7 and a complex key):

ID-Level-1, ID-Level-2, ID-Level-3, ID-Level-4, ID-Level-5, ID-Level-6, ID-Level-7

Or, create some sort of a tree of hierarchical levels and use the various key values as identifiers/foreign keys?

Comment: Given a node, is there only one path to the root? In other words, is this a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_graph) or a [DAG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph)?

Comment: @Branko: It's a tree (not DAG).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could model this like the following

```
class Company {
    static hasMany = [subdivisions: Subdivision]
}

class Subdivision {
    static belongsTo = [company: Company, subdivision: Subdivision]
    static hasMany = [subdivisions: Subdivision]
}
```

Comment: This approach seems more "Grails" like.

Answer (score 0):

Store it just like you described: Company->Div->Subdiv:

```
id  subdivision_name   subdivision_level    subdivision_path
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 1  ABC                0                    ABC
 2  Div1               1                    ABC->Div1
 3  Div2               1                    ABC->Div2
 4  Div3               1                    ABC->Div3
 5  SubDiv1            2                    ABC->Div1->SubDiv1
 6  SubDiv2            2                    ABC->Div1->SubDiv2
 7  SubDiv3            2                    ABC->Div1->SubDiv3
 8  DEF                0                    DEF
 9  Div1               1                    DEF->Div1
10  Div2               1                    DEF->Div2
11  Div3               1                    DEF->Div3
```

Number of levels is only limited by length of subdivision_path - standard datatypes should be more than enough.

So let's associate an address with ABC->Div1->SubDiv3:

```
CREATE TABLE addresses (id ... , subdivision_id INTEGER, ...);
ALTER TABLE addresses ADD CONSTRAINT fk_addresses_subdivisions FOREIGN KEY (subdivision_id) REFERENCES subdivisions (id);
```

... query all instances for Div2 and all of Div2's subdivisions.

```
SELECT * FROM subdivisions WHERE subdivision_path LIKE 'ABC->Div2%';
```

... for all subdivisions of Div2:

```
SELECT * FROM subdivisions WHERE subdivision_path LIKE 'ABC->Div2->%';
```

... for all root companies:

```
SELECT * FROM subdivisions WHERE level = 0;
```

... and more.

Alternatively subdivision_path can store ids, not names (maybe it's even better).